# Cloning in-memory image in JavaScript /jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, clone, append

This is probably a really simple one but I couldn't find the answer.

I have the following JavaScript/jQuery code where I am trying to create loading messages:

```
// preload an image to use for dynamic loading icon whenever requested
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loadingIcon = document.createElement('img');
    loadingIcon.src = '../images/ajax-loader.gif';
    window.loadingIcon = loadingIcon; // chache in global var
});
```

I wanted to cache the image on load so I'm not requesting it each time I want a loading message. Am I actually acheiving this with the above code?

The idea is that there's a lot of dynamic content on the page, and at any time I might have several different loading icons active.

I add the loading icon wherever with:

```
$('#myElem').appendChild(window.loadingIcon);
```

This doesn't actually work though, when I try to show a new loading icon, it just moves the previous one, so I can't have more than one on the page at a time.

I'm assuming I need to clone the element?

I tried to wrap the element in a jQuery object to use clone with `$(window.loadingIcon).clone()` but that didn't work (the function errored).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *could* clone the element, yes. But you can just as well create a new `<img>` element. If the image src has already been loaded by the browser, the image data will be cached and no further network-load will occur. You don't need to cache the element itself to cache the resource it's pointed at.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the image as a jQuery object:

```
var $loadingIcon = $('<img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
```

And then you should be able to clone it when you need to use it:

```
$('#myElem').append( $loadingIcon.clone() );
```

Answer (score 1):

javascript has a native `cloneNode` method, at least in IE7, which is all I have at the moment. I'm pretty sure it's cross browser.

this should do what you want:

```
$('#myElem').appendChild(window.loadingIcon.cloneNode());
```